# Serving Angular app from python web server

Tags: python, web-services, angular, angular-http

I have built a basic Angular app which display the message "app works" and a basic Python web server. My aim is to send HTTP get requests from my Angular to my python web server and get response back. How to trigger the Angular app from my python web server? I am trying to do "ng build" and calling my python web server, which is not really working. Help!

Comment: you need to serve your angular app content (the html, js, and css files) from your web server. there are several python web servers, so the specifics vary

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the response. Could you please point me to one such web server example? Also It is serving from the default "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" command but not through my web server.

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` should serve statically the local content, if i remember correctly. So if you have your angular app there, it should simply work.

Comment: you may want to define "which is not really working" which is not super specific

Comment: @njzk2 My angular app is not firing up from my python web server code. I am sure that I am missing on something but not understanding. What do I need add on my web server side to trigger my angular app on a given localhost port?

Comment: "My angular app is not firing up" ?